# after delete redirect to the page from where the delete request came

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very simple use case :-

If a delete request for a "role" comes from "users/show" then delete the role and redirect to users_show

If delete request for a "role" comes from "xyz/show" then delete the role and redirect to xyz_show

I do not want to pass params with the link_to, is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: @jvnill redirect_to :back does not work

Comment: hehe you should've tried the other options in that answer like the selected answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
redirect_to request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```

see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to